# When JSF 2.0 will be released?

Tags: java, jsf, frameworks, jakarta-ee

I got interested in looking at JSF 2.0 as a potential technology to use. Does anybody know when this version is scheduled to come out and how active is the project in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anybody know when this version is scheduled to come out

JSF 2.0 is part of Java EE 6 (i.e. any Java EE 6 container supports it) and has been elaborated under [JSR-314](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) (which is final since 01 Jul, 2009) but, as mentioned on the JCP web page:

> Sun will deliver a Reference Implementation (RI) and Technology Compatibility Kit (TCK). The RI will be made available **standalone** and as part of the Java EE 6 platform.

The RI is [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) and is **already available**. As written in [Mojarra 2.0.0 is available!](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/mojarra_2_0_0_is) (Oct 19, 2009):

> There are several ways to obtain the
>   release.
>
> - GlassFish V3 promoted build 69 (out later this week)
> - Download directly from http://javaserverfaces.java.net
> - Download using Maven2 using information provided [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)

You actually don't need a full Java EE 6 server. For example, check out the post [JSF 2.0 and Tomcat](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2009/12/29/jsf-20-and-tomcat) or [Integrating JSF 2.0 and Weld with Tomcat6](http://www.publicstaticfinal.de/2009/10/22/integrating-jsf-2-0-and-weld-with-tomcat6/). But I'd simply go for GlassFish v3 (or JBoss 5.2+ which also supports JSF 2.0 + CDI).

> how active is the project in general?

<strike>What project? The RI? What do you mean exactly?</strike> Well, Mojarra  is used in GlassFish so I consider it as a serious project, with dedicated man power. However, I don't expect extreme activity now that the spec is final, only maintenance and bugfix releases.

Comment: Pascal, thanks for the response and for the Maven link. I get it, the Maven references the Sun's repository at http://download.java.net/maven/2

>>> What project? The RI? What do you mean exactly? <<<

Yes, the RI project. I was confused by the Sun's page (http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) which references PR as the latest version. The Mojarra pages are pretty current.

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 is [included in Java EE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part2.html), and Glassfish v3 currently supports it.  It'll also run in WebSphere 7, [with some effort](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5410461).

Answer (score 1):

[JSF 2.0](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) was already final several months ago ([19 october 2009](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)) and it's indeed included in the [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) which was made final about one month ago ([10 december 2009](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316)).

Although it's been released along with Servlet 3.0 API in Java EE 6, JSF 2.0 is backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5. So you can either download it separately and run on any Servlet 2.5 capable webcontainer like [Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/), or just download a full fledged Java EE 6 implementation including it like [Glassfish v3](http://glassfish.java.net).